# is an android API essentially just using GET/POST to get information?

Tags: android, api

I'm trying to get the root of an API and I'm just wondering if most APIs are essentially using GET/POST requests to send and receive information?

My thought is that anything that android does with an API has to connect to some server somewhere, but is there a connecting language between the server and android? or can it essentially be explained like Android is sending a GET/POST request to a PHP page that makes calls to a database (if a database is involved)?

Example. If I'm very comfortable with php, can I make an API that references the php page?

Answer (score 0):

yes u can use php or there is some backend providers that offer alot of good stuff 
[backendless](https://backendless.com/products/documentation/) or parse.com
but if u already have your php services dame u can use them by the HTTPRequests / HTTPResponses using this in some asynch task will make it eazy